# Delayed setup in C# constructor

Tags: c#

Hello I was wondering how I can setup several things in a constructor, but have it wait until right after the object is created. I am thinking along the lines of my C++ and QT days when I would create a singleshot timer for 0 seconds that would fire my setup method as soon as the object was constructed. Can I do that in C#?

I don't mind doing all the work I do in the constructor just simply seeing if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is with just putting your stuff in the constructor is - there is nothing you cant do. Maybe an example of why you would like to do this / what problem you are having, would allow us to give you a more suited answer.

Although if you really need to delay code,

```
public constructor()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(...delay...);
        //delayed code
    });
}
```

Comment: I can do that, but in QT I did it to give the appearance that the object loaded faster and really it just constructed faster then I would setup the state of the internals. Basically It will speed up initial loads and I can put the data in after the object is created without explicitly calling a load method after constructing.

Comment: @twreid: then just start your load in a new task (like my example) without the Thread.Sleep()

Comment: however, the performance is probably negligible and wouldnt make much of a difference.

Answer (score 4):

In C# whole object is created before executing constructor - all fields are initialized with their default or initial values (if any). If you want to delay something, consider using [lazy initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx).

Comment: Oh ok so no need for my single shot timers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you are asking is to have a static method that constructs the desired object:

```
class MyObject {
    private MyObject() {

    }

    private void Setup() {
        // do some configuration here
    }

    public static MyObject CreateObject() {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        obj.Setup();
        return obj;   
    }
}
```

Thus, you never use the class' actual constructor but instead invoke the static method that creates the object and sets it up at the same time. I am not sure why you would want to do this though, since the effect from the point of view of the caller is the same -- you wait until the object is created and its setup is complete to be able to use it.

Comment: not sure what purpose or advantage this would serve. its not really what he was asking.